# .NET 4.5.1 - View return value in Autos

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Microsoft finally added support for seeing the return value in .NET 4.5.1 but I could never see 'result' in the Autos window and I never pursued it.

Months later, the whole team is now trying to work out why they also don't see it in the Autos window and so I'm newly interested in getting to the bottom of why this new feature doesn't seem to actually work.

In a .NET 4.5.1 under VS 2013.5 debugger, how can I see the return value when stopped at the end brace of a method?

Comment: You can't see it until the method returns to the caller.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General, ensure that the Compatibility Mode options are turned off.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I see it now and feel dumb in hindsight. You may add a proper answer and I'll tick it.